# Don't Print JSON Response (cURL)

Tags: php, json, http, curl

I am working with reCAPATCHA on a web form. I validate the CAPTCHA server side via cURL.

```
$post = [
    'secret' => '6LeGbxkUAAAAAGOiOLDlzRiLV6JBMSF5nTyObE9G',
    'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
];

//cURL and confirm the reCAPTCHA
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($response['success'] == true) {
    header("Location: https://website.com/contact.php?res=1");
} else {
    //print('reCAPTCHA failed.');
    header("Location: https://website.com/contact.php?res=2");
}
```

The JSON response is `{ "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }`

What happens is cURL automatically prints the JSON to the browser, preventing me from redirecting the page. Is there a way to either prevent cURL from printing the JSON or redirecting a different way? I have tried looking through documentation and other places and have not found an answer. I have also tried printing `$response` as a string and encoding it as JSON, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Without adding the given answer can you tell me what response you have stored in your variable `$response`

Comment: Please share the response you are getting in `$response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`, the script wouldn't validate the response properly because it was validating against a boolean rather than a string. I needed to add that line and put quotes around `'true'`.

Comment: remove this answer and edit your question by this phrase;

Answer (score 1):

Add this into you curl setopt

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: That does not work because it outputs `$response` as a string, not JSON. I needs to be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution can will be use this script how service, and call from Javascript. Finally do redirect in Javascript.

Comment: It needs to be in an external PHP script.

Answer (score -1):

> What happens is cURL automatically prints the JSON to the browser,

so you need to :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

then , to be able to manipulate your json , you will need to decode it as follows :

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

then you can easily check it as you wrote in your script

```
if($response['success'] == true) {
    header("Location: https://website.com/contact.php?res=1");
} else {
    //print('reCAPTCHA failed.');
    header("Location: https://website.com/contact.php?res=2");
}
```

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't validate properly.

Comment: how does it validate then?

Comment: It returns true even when the JSON value is false.